# What kind of metaphor is "colors of the wind"?

Tags: creative-writing, figures-of-speech

What kind of metaphor is "color of the wind"? I am not sure it's a metaphor, because we're attributing some traits that shouldn't be associated to wind. It's a figure of speech, but I don't know if it's a metaphor or something else or several figures of speech combined.

I am referring to the song: "Colors of the wind".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colors_of_the_Wind

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE director , glad to have you here. To learn more about us, check out our [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 1):

It's a literary metaphor. The style encourages the opposite of the goals of most non-fiction. In these instances the writer will point to a semi-ambiguous area and leave the reader to define the specifics. It fires the imagination of the reader and engages them.

I have used (on more than one occasion): "He kissed me in such a pretty way." (Or some variation of the same).

Colours (due to the defined spectrum) are often used metaphorically. Minnie Ripperton said, "No one else can make me feel the colours than you bring."

It means whatever you want it mean.

Comment: What distinguishes a literary metaphor from an ordinary metaphor?